# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with Reflections

Tags: java, reflection, nosuchmethoderror

Im getting this error and I'm really not sure why, it was working fine for the few days I was using it, then today when I went to use it (changed nothing) it just stopped working...?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
    at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:380) ~[?:?]
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126) ~[?:?]
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:168) ~[?:?]
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:141) ~[?:?]
    at me.realm.commons.reflection.Reflect.getClassesExtending(Reflect.java:14) ~[?:?]
```

My maven dependencies (and I've included it in the project build path)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My code that throws the error:

```
public static <T> Set<Class<? extends T>> getClassesExtending(Class<T> clazz) {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(""); //<-- this line
    Set<Class<? extends T>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(clazz);

    if (classes.size() <= 0) {
        Logger.warn("No classes extending " + clazz.getCanonicalName());
        return classes;
    }

    return classes;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you change version of reflections dependency? Or add Guava (or another dependencies with guava) to your project? Looks like [libraries conflict](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/194).

Comment: In my opinion, one should never invoke private method of a third party library! The reason is, exactly the error that you received! A library can change the private method at any time, as library provider is not bound to provide that private method throughout the life! (IF it is your own class then invoking private method is still ok though should be avoided). In this case, check the maven dep tree, and find if the said library is coming twice or not via children dependencies... then exclude the one which is not required in this case... but there are multiple possibilities with limited info

Comment: I was unable to reproduce that. Are you show actual dependencies? It is look like there is conflicting versions of `com.google.guava`.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/3e0329e47c326c0bab4a463616928fe8

The class Sets$SetView isnt there in the libraries prior to compiling
But I compile, error gets thrown (obviously), but then I look in the compiled .jar file and it says it's there?

https://gyazo.com/4fa03e6033fc5adbd13729f99546e4f8

Comment: @talex How were you unable to reproduce that?

Comment: @Realmm I create empty project with dependencies your provide. It runs without exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, turns out there was clashing versions of Guava, thanks for the help everyone